# determine if Microsoft Teams is in import mode

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I create a Microsoft team for use with the import APIS:
( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/import-messages/import-external-messages-to-teams)

```
Team newTeam = new Team()
{
   DisplayName = "TestMigration1",
   Description= "TestMigration with Import Api",
   AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
   {
        { "template@odata.bind", "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamsTemplates('standard')" },
        { "@microsoft.graph.teamCreationMode", "migration" }
   },
   CreatedDateTime = new DateTime(2020, 01, 01)             
};
```

The question is: how can I determine if the Team is still in import mode?
I created a team in migration mode and then reread it.
The returned Team does not return @microsoft.graph.teamCreationMode in the additional data, but I know that it is in migration mode because I didn't send the CompleteMigration Post.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**This behavior is expected.**

To check if a team is still in import mode, you can use the "[List joined teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-joinedteams?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)" or "[Get team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)" API and check the visibility property of the team.

The visibility property will be set to "private" when the team is in import mode, and the migration is not yet completed. After the migration is completed, the visibility property will be set to "public."

Comment: testing visibility is not the right trick. Our teams are created with visibility set to public. If I create it in import mode with visiblity set to public, and then "get" the team, the visibility flag is public, not private. Will test the joined teams

Comment: Have you tested this with joined teams API?

Comment: no, join team call fails, I didn't figure out why.

Comment: Could you please share the error which you are getting while executing API?